# mysql field data is array how can select item

Tags: php, mysql

table Name Data

```
ID  | Name | List
-----------------
1   | Test 1 | 1,2,4,6
2   | Test 2 | 2,4
3   | Test 3 | 4,6,7
3   | Test 4 | 2
```

how can select items from 'data' table where 'list' have 2 ?

after run query want see this result :

```
ID  | Name | List
-----------------
1   | Test 1 | 1,**2**,4,6
2   | Test 2 | **2**,4
3   | Test 4 | **2**
```

Comment: You should normalize your table. 1 row per value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Yes, as @chris85 states.  This is a horrible way to do it and will cause endless headaches.

Comment: Use find_in_set(2,list)

Comment: quick/dirty hack: [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). proper fix: normalize your design before you cause yourself any more trouble.

Comment: @marc-b agreed bro.. Best way to normalized yur table else use find in set or LIKE

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestion:**

First of all you need to normalize your table structure as one list Id in one row else you can use `FIND_IN_SET`

**Solution**:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,List);
```

**Suggestion 2**:

One more suggestion you can also create a separate table for saving list Id against data id benefit is that name field  which is string column will not repeat just suggestion.